# A split second error on StreamBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx, stream-builder

I'm trying to write full app for the first time as a beginner. I'm using getx in this app too.

I'm taking a split second `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0` while using StreamBuilder. It is working fine after that split second red error page. How I am supposed to deal with this, should I use something related with getx to stream the data?

This is my StreamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<KTCardItem> collectionList = filterByTag(snapshot.data!.docs);
          return PageView.builder(
            controller: PageController(keepPage: true),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: collectionList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
              return NFTCardView(
                index: index,
                isFavorite: isFavoritedByUser(index),
                ktCardItem: collectionList[index],
                onFavChanged: () {
                  onFavoriteChanged(collectionList[index].eventId ?? "", index);
                },
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        // filter the list by choice of tag
      },
    );
```

I'm guessing that cause of this problem is the filterByTag method that I do before the return. filterByTag method:

```
  List<KTCardItem> filterByTag(List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    List<KTCardItem> collectionList = [];
    for (var document in snapshot) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (data["tags"].contains(_tag.value)) {
        collectionList.add(KTCardItem.fromMap(data));
      }
    }
    return collectionList;
  }
```